# How to include one empty line in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need more space after chapter one completion on how to include empty line space in the table of contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are not providing any `MWE`, assumed that you are using standard `book` template, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Test}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```